# Is there a way to emulate an android application within a windows program?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, emulation, unreal-development-kit, unreal-engine4

I realize it is an odd request, but I'm trying to enable an android app running within a windows program. It doesn't technically need to run within the program, but I would like to display the android app interface within my program along with being able to interact with the app. Anyone ever tried anything like this or could point me in the right direction? If it helps, I'm looking to do this within either a unity or unreal engine simulation.

Answer (score 1):

Did you have a look at [BlueStacks](http://www.bluestacks.com/app-player.html)? It allows you to run Android app on Windows or Mac. You can try then to interact with it in a standard for Win/Mac way. But, since BlueStacks doesn't provide any API to access the application, you'll have to inject hooks on display related WinApi functions by yourself. And that's not the simplest task.
As an alternative I can suggest you to run Android app inside VirtualBox and use its [SDK](https://www.virtualbox.org/sdkref/interface_i_display.html) to access the app output and display it where you like to. You may also check the AndroVM project (predecessor of Genymotion) and its [SDL player](https://github.com/androvm/SDLplayer).

Comment: Is there a way to grab the output of BlueStacks though?  I don't see how you could embed something like that in a unity simulation, but I might just not be understanding your suggestion.